# Shiny with HTML UI:

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am converting a small legacy web that currently uses R, RApache and PHP to use only R and Shiny instead. One of the requirements is to use HTML UI instead of the regular Shiny `UI.R`.

I have a file that includes some HTML text that should be rendered as such in the webpage. Actually it is assigned to a `<span>` tag that has assigned as id `textoIntro` and as class `shiny-text-output`.

I can easily load the content of this file and assign it to the span using following code in `server.R`:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # loading file info
    introFile <- 'path/file.txt'
    textoIntro <- readChar(introFile, file.info(introFile)$size)

    output$textoIntro <- renderText({HTML(textoIntro)})
})
```

But by doing this the text is not considered by the browser as HTML. Instead it is shown as "raw text":

```
<p>lorem ipsum </p> dolor sit amet...
```

I need it to load as HTML, like this:

> **lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet

I have already tried to use `renderPrint`, but the effect is the same.

I know there is the `HTML` Shiny function, but I understand it has to be used in conjunction with the `tag` function, which as far as I know is intended for `UI.R`.

Anyone can give me a hint on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @guillem-vicens I'm also facing this problem. Could you share the final working code? I'm trying to follow your post but can't get the point. Salut

Comment: Hi @guillem-vicens , no need to post the code. I've just found a problem with path for txt file. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class for your `<span>` tag should be `shiny-html-output`, not `shiny-text-output`.

Comment: can you explain how to set the `<span>` tag?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `renderUI` -- this should return it as HTML.

Comment: Did not work completely although it was quite better. The `HTML`tags were parsed but the special characters (such as á in HTML) were not correctly parsed. Anyway, +1 since it might work for others.